# Notepad++ How to upload file from Workspace or Project panel?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying Notepad++ 6.8.8 as my coding editor. I installed the NppFTP plugin, am able to connect to my server and folder, and I can upload opened files from my edit window. What I would like to do is to upload a file or files directly from the workspace file explorer panel on the left. Not all files, for instance, are text editable files. I have image files I would like to upload directly from the project panel, without having to open them in the editor window.

Comment: In the file tab you can go to open, then select the folder...

Comment: @ewrwr Not sure that's the right way to upload file types like images. I don't actually want to open an image file in the editor. I only want to upload it directly from the Project panel, the same as I would with Dreamweaver.